# json unescaped unicode php 5.3

Tags: php, json, laravel, unicode

im parsing a list of question in laravel in json in php 5.3 ans im getting this result

```
{"status":"ok","questions":[{"questionId":1,"question":"Comment appelle-t-on un petit morceau de pain long et fin que l'on trempe dans un \u0153uf \u00e0 la coque?","rightAnswer":"Une mouillette","explanation":null,"wrongAnswer1":"Une touillette","wrongAnswer2":"Une miette","wrongAnswer3":"Une grenouillette","theme":"COMMERCE","category":"BOULANGERIE","difficulty":1,"created_at":"2014-08-22 00:00:00","updated_at":"2014-08-22 00:00:00"},{"questionId":2,"question":"Quelle op\u00e9ration consiste \u00e0 m\u00e9langer la farine, l'eau, le sel et la levure pour fabriquer de la p\u00e2te \u00e0 pain?","rightAnswer":"Le p\u00e9trissage","explanation":"La p\u00e2te est diff\u00e9rente selon la technique de p\u00e9trissage utilis\u00e9e.","wrongAnswer1":"Le touillage","wrongAnswer2":"Le moulage","wrongAnswer3":"Le levage","theme":"COMMERCE","category":"BOULANGERIE","difficulty":2,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},{"questionId":3,"question":"Pourquoi le boulanger fait-il des fentes sur les pains avant leur cuisson?","rightAnswer":"Pour qu'ils n'\u00e9clatent pas.","explanation":"Ces fentes qui forment de petits traits sur le pain s'appellent des \"grignes\".","wrongAnswer1":"Pour les d\u00e9corer.","wrongAnswer2":"Pour signer sa cr\u00e9ation.","wrongAnswer3":"Pour qu'ils ne gonflent pas trop.","theme":"COMMERCE","category":"BOULANGERIE","difficulty":3,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}]}
```

here is the code

```
public function index()
{
    $questions = questionList::all();

    return Response::json(array(
    'status' => 'ok',
    'questions' => $questions->toArray())
    );
}
```

the thing is that json_unescaped_unicode don't work in php 5.3 it work in php 5.4 so is tere an equivalent or a way to replace  \u0153uf \u00e0  on these é è à thx :)

Comment: Nothing trivial, no. Why is this so important in the first place? It works fine as is, no?

Comment: when it will be parsed it will look good ????

Comment: @deceze : The French letters as "é, è, à" are not parsed and the output is, for instance, 'op\u00e9ration' instead of 'opération'. This problem occured only in PHP <= 5.3.

Comment: Please peruse the linked duplicate. Let me know should that not answer your question.

Comment: @Debflav How exactly is that a "problem"?

Comment: @deceze : The output is weird and the option `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` does not exist in PHP <= 5.3. I guess Ahmed wants a solution for this PHP version. Maybe I'm wrong. Edit: I understand, your point of view, we can't say it's a problem...

Comment: @Debflav The output is *valid JSON*. It may be *nicer* to have unescaped Unicode characters in your JSON for the purpose of a human reading the JSON, but since this should only be necessary during a short period of debugging if at all it's hardly worth trying to "fix" it. There's nothing *wrong*, and there's no quick fix, and there's no reason to invest significant energy into developing a fix.